# In-class struct, how does "this" work?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct, this

As stated, how does the `this` pointer act when called in a struct defined in a class ?
Let's say I have the following piece of code:

```
class A {
public:
    struct {
        void bar() {  std::cout << this << std::endl;  }
    } foo;
};

int main() {
    A a; a.foo.bar();
    std::cout << &a << std::endl;
    std::cout << &a.foo << std::endl;
}
```

That generate this output:

```
0x62fe9f
0x62fe9f
0x62fe9f
```

`a.foo` share the same address with `a`, how could one access to the `this` pointer of `foo` ?

Using `this->foo` raise an error:

`test.cpp:20:23: error: 'struct A::<anonymous>' has no member named 'foo'`

Comment: *Where* do you use `this->foo`? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the *failing* program?

Comment: a & foo will indeed share the same address - since foo is the first member of A.  That's why knowing the type of object matters.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  First, it appears to me that `struct S` is completely irrelevant, your question is only about `A` and `A::foo`.  Second, `A::foo::bar()` *does* access "the `this` pointer of (A::)`foo`".  So what is the problem?

Comment: Here's a hint: insert an `int` variable into `A` (right after the `public` keyword) and see how the output changes

Comment: I wrongly understand my problem, indeed `this` in `foo` will point to `foo` and thus have the same adress as `a`, being his first member ! So how to acces the `a` pointer inside `foo` ?

Comment: @Usiten You can't. `A` knows of `foo` but `foo` never knows of `A`. You can cast some memory around and trick the compiler but that is nasty.

Comment: @Usiten, you need to pass it there yourself. `this` is not special, it's just a pointer with a distinct name.

Comment: Alright, thanks ! That's the answers I needed, plus the validate answer !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The address is mostly just where the memory if the object "starts". How much to offset is needed members is then defined by the class definition.

So class `A` "starts" at `0x62fe9f`.

At the beginning of class `A` is the member `foo` so because there is nothing in front of it it has also address `0x62fe9f` etc.

When you change the class to

```
class A {
public:
    int i;
    struct {
        void bar() {  std::cout << this << std::endl;  }
    } foo;
};
```

You shloud see `&a.i` and `&a` having the same address and `&a.foo` should be `&a + sizeof(int)`

(*Note:* It may be more than `sizeof(int)` and in other cases also different because how padding is set. This is just a simple example. **You should not rely on this in real code**)

Comment: This is not intended to be used in real code, but was just a wonder of how it works ! And after testing, without optimization flags, my compiler add `sizeof(int)`, no padding

Comment: @Usiten this was not directed at you. But these answers are also for other people. It is to make sure nobody else does. And `sizeof(int)` with defaults usually fits. If you use a `char` instead of `int` it can happen that it is more than `sizeof(char)` (depending on compiler and CPU).

Comment: @Usiten also often the `virtual` implementation will place at first slot pointer to `vtable` needed to handle virtual calls over `(A *)` instance, that would shift `&a.i` immediately (but it depends of course on how particular compiler implements virtual functions calling, and also it may differ per platform, especially 32b vs 64b). (just add `virtual` to `A::bar()` in zwol's answer to see it in action).

Answer (score 3):

Possibly this modified version of your program, and its output, will be enlightening.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class A {
public:
  int data;

  struct {
    int data;
    void bar()
    {
      cout << this << '\n';
      cout << &this->data << '\n';
    }
  } foo;

  void bar()
  {
    cout << this << '\n';
    cout << &this->data << '\n';
    cout << &this->foo << '\n';
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  A a;
  cout << &a << '\n';
  a.bar();
  a.foo.bar();
}
```